# How do I make pyre-check library work with numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pyre-check

a.py:

```
import numpy
```

pyre

```
a.py:1:0 Undefined import [21]: Could not find a module corresponding to import `numpy`.
```

Although definitely I have numpy installed.

Environment: Ubuntu, python 3.7.1, pyre 0.0.22, numpy 1.16.2

Comment: `pyre` is a static analysis tool aimed to write better programs. How is writing better programs not about programming?

Comment: Have you checked that numpy exists within your `venv/bin`. It might be that your venv is being clever and bringing a cached numpy from your global install. So when Pyre reads your `venv/bin` it can't find numpy

Answer (score 3):

Ok, got it. Need to install [numpy-stubs](https://github.com/numpy/numpy-stubs)

Comment: This has since been deprecated and moved to NumPy